# I hid my email using some CSS, however users cannot highlight the text now

Tags: html, css

I am trying to hide my email from bots on my website, I included the code below in my < head > section

```css
.e-mail:before {
  content: attr(data-website) "\0040" attr(data-user);
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
  direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<p> Contact Me: <span class="e-mail" data-user="emaNtesT" data-website="moc.liamg"></span></p>
```

The proper email appears, but I am not able to highlight it to copy and paste it, how would I go about trying to fix this?

Comment: Is this reproducible in a code snippet or js fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As much bots don't run JavaScript, they **will** be able to read your page's source code and register your email address in their database if they want to.

In my opinion, the best way to avoid bots is to mark your page as a page not to be followed nor indexed using the following code in your `<head>`:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow"/>
```

Comment: How would this stop bots, wouldn't they just read the page anyways? Excuse my ignorance I am new to web development

Comment: The type of bots that scrape email addresses will not respect `noindex,nofollow`. It would also stop legitimate bots (search engines) from indexing your page.

Comment: Oh I see thank you, and one last separate piece of question, what do you think of including mailto: and tel:? I have heard some people saying to use them and others not to, I was just curious on your opinion

Comment: This will not stop bot from reading your page but it will prevent them from indexing your page in search engines. `nofollow` will prevent bots from following links on your page. If you want non-legitimate bots not to register your email address, don't use `mailto:` and insert an email address like `myname [at] mydomain [dot] com`